# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect() How to resolve?

Tags: php, db2, odbc

I am running MAMP and attempting to connect to ibm db2, however running into issues. It seems `db_connect` and `odbc_connect` are unavailable. How do I resolve? PHP version 7.2.1.

`Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()`

I appreciate any guidance. thanks in advance for your  help.

Comment: This appears to be a FAQ. Have you installed and configured an IBM Db2 driver See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/t0070148.html . Then have you installed and configured the php extension for ibm_db2 ? See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.php.doc/doc/c0054926.html  . As this appears to be frequently asked, I suggest you do more research , it may get you up and running faster than waiting for answers.